# Yii2 Image Popup in kartik gridview

Tags: yii, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app, yii-components

I need help in displaying image in Kartik gridview Yii2.

Please give me suggestion to show image in popup when we click on it.

/* Script to load the image in popup */

```
  'attribute' => 'image',
        'width' => '50px',
        'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
            if ($model->image != '') {
                return Html::a(Html::img(Yii::$app->params['server'] . "/mypath/uploadedfile/" .
                                        Yii::$app->session['city'] . "/" . $model->image, ['width' => '70px', 'height' => '70px']), '#', [
                            'title' => Yii::t('app', 'View Image'),
                            'class' => 'view-image-link',
                            'data-id' => $model->image,
                ]);
            } else {
                return "No Image";
            }


            $this->registerJs("    
                $('.view-image-link').click(function()
                {
                    $.get
                        (
                            'viewimage',
                            {
                                id: $(this).data('id')
                            },
                            function(data) 
                            {
                                $('.modal-body').html(data);
                                $('#imageview').modal();
                            }
                        );
                });");
```

Comment: What have you tried? Do your own research first and post the problems you encounter here. StackOverflow is here to help us learn, not do the work for us.

Comment: @Ianthe the Duke of Nukem : I had asked for suggestion not for work.  :)
Please check my edited question. i have used Yii2 modal dialog box. but not working when i expand grid. can u pls suggest any idea on this.
thanks in advance

Comment: Used Modal dialog 

Modal::begin([
                    'id' => 'imageview',
                    'footer' => '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>',
                ]);

                Modal::end();

Comment: Is you image path is correct? like `http://localhost/yii2-app/uploades/cool.png`

Comment: @Muhammad Shahzad :  Yes path is perfect. As i see view source the path of image in corret but not loading in popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Changing I have resolved my self

Modal dialog
 `Modal::begin([ 'id' => 'imageview', 'footer' => '<a href="#" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>', ]); Modal::end();`